# How can I see the predictor function that Mathematica produces?

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying some basic machine learning with Mathematica. I am wondering if I can see the function that Mathematica produces for a training set. I give the following example:

trainingset = {1 -> 1.3, 2 -> 2.4, 3 -> 4.4, 4 -> 5.1, 6 -> 7.3};
p = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "LinearRegression"]

If I type p[1.5], it will give me the predicted value. However, could I also see/know somehow the function used, e.g. for this case in the form of y=a*x+b, (where x is the variable)? Is there a way to see the predicted function?

Comment: Have a look at the result of `p[[1]]` and you'll see the internals.  An important thing to realize is that the resulting linear regression model is fit against the **standardized** data, not the original data. This is quite common for Mathematica to pre-standardize before learning, and it makes extracting the model a bit awkward because the parameters have to be un-standardized properly. See here for example with SVMs https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/233099/how-to-find-explicit-hyperplane-in-supportvectormachine/233599#233599

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that `PredictorFunction`s are implemented in a nice and transparent way as `PredictorFunction[ Association[...]]`. So execute `p[[1]]` and everything is laid out nicely for you.

Comment: Thank you Henrik, this was very helpful! Still though, I don't get how can I see the function. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Well, the actual predictor consists of one or more neural nets with pre- and postprocessors. Very complicated. You can try to inspect `trace = Trace[p[1.5]];` in order to guess what is going on... The working of `FindFit` or `LinearModelFit` might be easier to graps.

Answer (score 0):

This `PredictorInformation[pd, "FunctionProperties"]` should do.

hope it helps ( :