# How to find explicit hyperplane in SupportVectorMachine

Tags: machine-learning, parameters

I am using the SupportVectorMachine classfier:

e.g., (* let me use Linear kernel for simplicity *)

```
cc = Classify[trainingData, 
   Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", 
     "KernelType" -> "Linear"
     }];
```

I would like to find the actual equation of the hyperplane  f(x) = w.x + b;

e.g.
I can find b by

```
Information[cc, "BiasParameter"]
```

But how do I find the support vector w?  I don't see an option for it:

```
Information[cc, "Properties"]
```

does NOT seem to contain this.

thanks a lot!!

J

Comment: I was going to post a full answer but because it's not entirely clear how the support vectors are encoded (offset), I wasn't sure how to get the hyperplane. Anyway try this (I'm on v12.1.1.0 so your mileage may vary): `model = cf[[1]]["Model"];
trainedModel = model["TrainedModel"][[1]];
sv = trainedModel["supportVectors"];
svc = trainedModel["supportVectorCoefficients"];
rho = trainedModel["rho"]; `

Comment: ^ if you test this with the following data: `SeedRandom[123];
training = 
  Join[Thread[RandomPoint[Disk[], 200] -> 0], 
   Thread[RandomPoint[Disk[{1.5, 1.5}, .7], 200] -> 1]];` and then classify via linear svm, then plot the vectors `ListPlot[training[[All, 1]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Opacity[.5], Red, Point[sv]}]` you'll notice the vectors seem to be offset from the plane front. Adding the centroid of the points closer to lining up but not perfectly. It's not clear why Mathematica represents the vectors this way. See here: https://pastebin.com/qfugeZpf

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really helpful! Surprised this is not given in any examples in the documentation.  I agree, bit odd it doesn't give the w in the hyper-plane, it should just really be a vector (normal vector to the hyper-plane)  - J

Comment: It's probably like that because this is an internal property, hence the `cf[[1]]` _(also note the unusual lower case initial 's' in  'supportVectorCoefficients')_. These internals can change between versions and I don't think there's an expectation the user will need them, so they are undocumented. I bountied your question because I'm also very much interested in how to get the hyperplane (y=mx+c line) from `sv`, `svc`, and `rho` in my comment.

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured this out!
Try running the below code, as mentioned in the comments:

```
SeedRandom[123];
training = 
  Join[Thread[RandomPoint[Disk[], 200] -> 0], 
   Thread[RandomPoint[Disk[{1.5, 1.5}, .7], 200] -> 1]];
cf = Classify[training, 
   Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", "KernelType" -> "Linear"}];
model = cf[[1]]["Model"];
trainedModel = model["TrainedModel"][[1]];
sv = trainedModel["supportVectors"];
svc = trainedModel["supportVectorCoefficients"];
rho = trainedModel["rho"];
ListPlot[training[[All, 1]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Opacity[.5], Red, Point[sv]}]
```

Unfortunately, the `"supportVectors"` are scaled and offset somehow and do not line up with any points:

[image: bad support vectors]

However, after much failed experimentation with `Rescale` and other transformations I finally realized that the points are scaled and offset using `Standardize`. If we standardize the whole list of points, the support vectors line up perfectly and we can get the hyperplane (line)! Therefore all we need to do is *un-standardize* the support vectors and the $y$ and $x$ intercepts of the hyperplane:

```
With[{points = training[[All, 1]]},
 sd = StandardDeviation[points];
 m = Mean[points];
 svadjusted = #*sd + m & /@ sv;
 (* the y and x intercepts, we still need to un-standardize these *)
 plane0 = {0, rho/Last[(svc.sv)]};
 plane1 = {rho/First[(svc.sv)], 0};
 Show[
  ListPlot[training[[All, 1]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Opacity[.5], Point[svadjusted],
     InfiniteLine[{plane0*sd + m, plane1*sd + m}]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: unstandardized points]

---

Here's everything wrapped up into a function that works for the linear kernel in either 2D or 3D:

```
Remove["Global`*"]

unstandardize[point_, sd_, mu_] := point*sd + mu;
getvectors[cf_ClassifierFunction, data_] := With[{p = data[[All, 1]]},
  With[{sd = StandardDeviation[p], mu = Mean[p]},
   unstandardize[#, sd, mu] & /@ 
    cf[[1]]["Model"]["TrainedModel"][[1]]["supportVectors"]
   ]]
getplane[svmcf_ClassifierFunction, data_] :=
 With[{tm = svmcf[[1]]["Model"]["TrainedModel"][[1]], 
   points = data[[All, 1]]},
  Module[{
    sv = tm["supportVectors"],
    svc = tm["supportVectorCoefficients"],
    sd = StandardDeviation[points],
    mu = Mean[points],
    dim = Length[points[[1]]],
    vecs, offset
    },
   vecs = 
    Rest[RotationMatrix[{svc.sv, PadRight[{1}, dim]}].IdentityMatrix[
       dim]];
   offset = With[{vars = Array[x, dim]},
     Values@First@FindInstance[vars.(svc.sv) == tm["rho"], vars]
     ];
   vecs = sd*# & /@ vecs;
   offset = unstandardize[offset, sd, mu];
   If[dim > 2, InfinitePlane[offset, vecs], 
    InfiniteLine[offset, First[vecs]]]
   ]
  ]
(* Test the 2D case *)
SeedRandom[123];
training2D = 
  Join[Thread[RandomPoint[Disk[], 400] -> 0], 
   Thread[RandomPoint[Disk[{1.5, 0.5}, .7], 400] -> 1]];
cf2D = Classify[training2D, 
   Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", "KernelType" -> "Linear"}];
Graphics[{Point[training2D[[All, 1]]], Red, PointSize[Large], 
  Point[getvectors[cf2D, training2D]], Opacity[.5], Gray, 
  getplane[cf2D, training2D]}]

(* Test the 3D case *)
training3D = 
  Join[Thread[RandomPoint[Ball[], 400] -> 0], 
   Thread[RandomPoint[Ball[{1.5, 0.5, 0.8}, .7], 400] -> 1]];
cf3D = Classify[training3D, 
   Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", "KernelType" -> "Linear"}];
Graphics3D[{Point[training3D[[All, 1]]], Red, PointSize[Large], 
  Point[getvectors[cf3D, training3D]], Opacity[.5], Gray, 
  getplane[cf3D, training3D]}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: SVM Support Vector Machine 2D and 3D hyperplanes]

Comment: For those wondering, the line equation and y/x intercepts came from rearranging this at $x=0$ and $y=0$ here: $\beta_1 x + \beta_2 y = \rho$ where $(\beta_1,\beta_2)^\top = \mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{v_s}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ is the weights vector `"supportVectorCoefficients"` and $\mathbf{v_s}$ are the `"supportVectors"` both taken from the classifier internals, and $\rho$ is `"rho"` in the above code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your beautiful work and explanations!!  This is really helpful!   Very strange that Mathematica does not have this documented. Perhaps you could write to Wolfram support about this improvement.  This is similar for all the other classifiers, all the parameters in those are rather hard to extract.

Comment: @JamesKhan thanks. Please accept this answer if you think this is adequate.

Answer (score -2):

Additional to the code from [@flinty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/72682/flinty) I strongly recommend reading the Mathematica documentation for [`SupportVectorMachine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/method/SupportVectorMachine.html). Especially the definition for the method option "Linear".

[image: excerpt from Mathematica documentation]

It has no further parameter just the input and the output of the rules are evaluated. Despite there are values for the parameters in the `Information`. This is a simple bilinear kernel for a supposed linear correlation.

Comment: Consider sharing this information as a comment with link to the documentation.

Comment: I am of the opinion that flinty ran short with the comment and so do I if I try.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.   Indeed, the linear kernel just says to use the ordinary dot product x1 \cdot x2; just like other kernels have their own parameters, like \gamma, etc.   But this still is not we are after:  we want the actual equation of the hyperplane, i.e., the weights w_i and bias b, so that we have a hyperplane equation:   
w1 x1 + w2 x2 + ... + wb xn = b.

In Python sklearn; we can extract this information by:

np.dot(svc.coef_[0], x) + b = 0.

curiously, we don't have this option.  Even with flinty's suggestion.

Comment: It is very disappointing that Mathematica makes a secret about the documentation. Why this?
It would be much better if Wolfram would describe exactly how the decision function is implemented such that user can work with it.

I strongly encourage Wolfram to do so.
Same with other Classification/regression methods, e.g. nearest Neighbors, etc.

This is important, especially if one wants to implement real world applications, e.g. in medicine or what ever.